# R misunderstanding lapply computation/output sequence?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have the created the following lapply command to compute multiple regression models from a list of dependant variables.

```
lapply(1:length(regressionVars$motivation_on), function(x) {
   print("printing regression model for DV: " %p%  regressionVars$motivation_on[x])
   OLS_ONM_motivation_X <- lm(regressionVars$motivation_on[x] %p% " ~ " %p% "age + gender" %p% " + " %p% paste(c(regressionVars$pvq), sep = "", collapse = " + "), comb)
   summary(OLS_ONM_motivation_X)
})
```

The output I get when I render the R file looks like this:
[image]

However what I really want is this sequence:

- print(headline1)
- summary(lm1)
- print(headline2)
- summary(headline2)
- and so on...

I also tried a for loop, but it only prints the "headline" 21 times and does not compute the linear models...

```
for (x in 1:length(regressionVars$motivation_on)) {
   print("printing regression model for DV: " %p%  regressionVars$motivation_on[x])
   OLS_ONM_motivation_X <- lm(regressionVars$motivation_on[x] %p% " ~ " %p% "age + gender" %p% " + " %p% paste(c(regressionVars$pvq), sep = "", collapse = " + "), comb)
   summary(OLS_ONM_motivation_X)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve that I want? Can anyone come up with a better title for this post?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @AdamQuek Just take any collection in R and iterate as the OP is doing...you'll see that the summary stats always appear at the end, _after_ the iteration is complete.

Comment: Note that in many cases `summary()` will also display a representation of the values being iterated, in which case your question is a moot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R functions implicitly return if the last line evaluates some object. So summary is being returned from the function rather than being printed. I believe you can do

```
print(summary(x))
```

instead to get the desired result, otherwise do the print and add a return(TRUE) to the next line or something to evade R's automatic return capture.

Try

```
invisible(lapply(1:length(regressionVars$motivation_on), function(x) {
   print("printing regression model for DV: " %p%  regressionVars$motivation_on[x])
   OLS_ONM_motivation_X <- lm(regressionVars$motivation_on[x] %p% " ~ " %p% "age + gender" %p% " + " %p% paste(c(regressionVars$pvq), sep = "", collapse = " + "), comb)
   print(summary(OLS_ONM_motivation_X))
}))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work based on my tests locally here.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine for me: `lapply(1:5, function(x) { print(x); print(summary(x)) }` as far as I can tell prints exactly in the sequence that is requested in the question. If you want to avoid the final printout of the returned results then wrap the whole in with `invisible()`.

Comment: No...your summaries are all printing _at the bottom_...read the output carefully

Comment: This is a misuse of `lapply`. If they don't want return values they should use a `for` loop.

Comment: @Roland If using a `for` loop solves the problem of the `summary` appearing out of place, then post that as an answer.

Comment: They print at the correct place AND at the bottom. I did say if you want to avoid it at the bottom you can just wrap the whole thing with invisible(). But yes this is definitely an incorrect usage of lapply and a for loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not doing anything without a reproducible example. They appear to use some kind of markdown/knitr.

Comment: As stated in the initial post I also tried a for loop - what did I do wrong there? :)